# StartApp SDK binding in android with xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk, banner, startapp

i'm working on an android app with xamarin, and i wanted to add a banner with StartApp SDK (v 3.6.1).

After i created a binding library, and import startapp.jar, when i build it, i've got this error:

```
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'StartAppAd' does not exist in the 
namespace 'Com.Startapp.Android.Publish.AdsCommon' (are you missing an 
assembly reference?) StartApp C:\Users\samih pc\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\Random Number\StartApp\obj\Debug\generated\src\Com.Startapp.Android.Publish.Cache.ACMConfig.cs 107 Active
```

how can i fix that? I don't know which assembly i missing.

Thanks a lot.

Regards, Sam.

Comment: i guess you have tried clean and rebuild right?

Comment: yes i did this, and i close/restart VS but it doesn't work.

Comment: in my case very often vs2017 doesnt let me rebuild somethng, so i open the project from 15 and i build it from there

Comment: Hey, i just follow that tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2grKT_ZJqcQ). but i have this following error : Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'Random_Number.AdListner' to 'Com.Startapp.Android.Publish.Banner.IBannerListener'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). How can i fix that?